# Linux Mint 19 no login screen

Tags: linux-mint, login

I have just created a bootable Linux USB and added three accounts: My Account, My brothers account and a Guest account. every time i boot Linux up it used to log me straight into the "mint" default account. I changed it so it would log into mine hoping that a login screen would show up since all the others accounts require a password. But it logs me straight into mine. I would like a logon screen to show up when i boot into Linux but this doesn't occur. I can switch users after it log's me in to another and it shows the logon screen there but not when i first boot it up. Is there is a way for a logon screen to show up after booting into Linux Mint 19 on a bootable USB?  Also would there be any way to disable the "mint" account. I am using Linux mint 19 Cinnamon.

Comment: What shows up in your System Settings -> Administration -> Login Window? (Or if no login window, then mdm or lightdm, etc)

Answer (score 3):

On install there is an option when creating your username to autologin or manual login.  To change this after install you need to:

menu --> Administration --> Login Window

Click the "Users" at the top, then delete the user that is in the "Username" box under Automatic Login.  Close and reboot and you should be presented with a list of users to login with.

Comment: there is no mdm file but there is a lightdm file. in it it says: [SeatDefaults] allow-guest=false allow-login-guest=false autologin-user=mint autologin-user-timeout=0 [seat:*] greeter-show-manual-login=true greeter-hide-users=true atologin-user=dextron.

Comment: I cannot edit the lightdm file even when I’m an admin

Comment: Edited answer above.  Did that work for you?

Comment: I have Linux on a live USB so I’m assuming I actually have to install it on a USB to use Linux properly

Comment: Yes, changes will not persist from reboots on a live USB.  Best way for you to do this is to do a full install of Mint on to a USB drive.  There are many ways to do this, one is to dd the image to a USB drive and another is explained here https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=186040&p=963551#p963551